# chrome.idle: how can I query the current detection interval?

Tags: google-chrome

You can do this:

```
chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval(60*60);
chrome.idle.onStateChanged.addListener(my_code)
```

However, someone on the browser console can then type in:

```
chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval(15);
```

...and this will affect the way that `my_code` is called. This is useful for debugging, but it begs the question: how can I query the *current* detection interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way (at least none that I or Google know of) to query the detection interval. However we know that the default is 60 seconds, and it's possible to override the function. (You just need to make sure that nobody calls `setDetectionInveral` in your app's environment before you overrode the function - and if you can't be sure, you would have to manually set the detection interval to a known value afterwards.)

Example:

```
var currentDetectionInterval = 60;
var originalSetDetectionInterval = chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval;
chrome.idle.setDetectionInterval = function(detectionIntervalInSeconds, callback) {
    currentDetectionInterval = detectionIntervalInSeconds;
    return originalSetDetectionInterval.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Optional, if you like this.
chrome.idle.getDetectionInterval = function() {
    return currentDetectionInterval;
};
```

This would allow you to query the detection interval by checking the variable `currentDetectionInterval`, or if you like this better, by using the new function `chrome.idle.getDetectionInterval` we just added.